# How to summarise all columns using group_by and summarise?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to tidy my daily activity data (accelerometer data). I would like to sum the repeated rows of each day for all columns. I have 32 rows (some are repeated) and 90 columns (data of one subject).

```
# Example of my data with 32 rows and 14 columns

df <- data.frame(LbNr = c(22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002),
Type = c("A2. Working" ,"A1. NonWorking" ,"A1. NonWorking" ,"A4. SleepWeek" ,"A1. NonWorking" ,"A2. Working" ,"A1. NonWorking" ,"A4. SleepWeek" ,"A4. SleepWeek" ,"A1. NonWorking" ,"A2. Working" ,"A1. NonWorking" ,"A1. NonWorking" ,"A4. SleepWeek" ,"A1. NonWorking" ,"A2. Working" ,"A1. NonWorking" ,"A4. SleepWeek" ,"A4. SleepWeek" ,"A1. NonWorking" ,"A2. Working" ,"A1. NonWorking" ,"A1. NonWorking" ,"C4. SleepWeekend" ,"C0. Leisure" ,"C0. Leisure" ,"C4. SleepWeekend" ,"C0. Leisure" ,"C4. SleepWeekend" ,"C4. SleepWeekend" ,"A1. NonWorking" ,"A2. Working"),
Weekday = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,1,1,1),
Time = c(0.66667,5.66667,0.35,6.15,1.5,9.83333,6.05,0.11667,6.83333,1.33333,9.83333,6,0.03333,7.2,6.43333,5,5.23333,0.1,6.41667,0.96667,11.01667,5.6,0.43333,7.9,15.66667,0.03333,7.91667,15.61667,0.43333,6.33333,0.66667,6.83333),
lie = c(0.00583,0.37778,0.03556,4.84389,0.05444,0.05972,0.67639,0.0125,5.68806,0.02333,0.65278,0.23889,0.00917,7.2,0.45472,0.38333,0.29694,0.08,5.48694,0.01889,0.01028,0.12139,0.01694,6.96028,0.24472,0.00333,6.93639,0.11833,0.41861,5.74889,0.00861,0.07333),
sit = c(0.31194,4.36167,0.14417,1.30611,0.45083,6.64111,4.14306,0.10417,1.14528,0.51167,5.79417,3.11833,0,0,2.23944,2.79722,3.66583,0.00472,0.92972,0.29917,6.76806,4.21056,0.30222,0.92194,9.77694,0.00417,0.91833,12.02972,0.01472,0.58444,0.15806,5.58694),
stand = c(0.13389,0.47111,0.09139,0,0.67278,1.63667,0.51806,0,0,0.46417,1.81917,1.57472,0.01889,0,1.88917,0.88639,0.63028,0.00667,0,0.3975,1.83417,0.72528,0.05889,0.00667,2.33944,0.01361,0.03639,1.78139,0,0,0.25472,0.41167),
move = c(0.09056,0.34444,0.05167,0,0.21611,0.59472,0.34306,0,0,0.21333,0.525,0.72806,0.00528,0,0.76583,0.39194,0.41861,0.00667,0,0.14056,1.04694,0.36944,0.03778,0.00806,2.44583,0.00944,0.02083,0.93083,0,0,0.15417,0.235),
walk = c(0.11528,0.10722,0.02722,0,0.10583,0.84194,0.35639,0,0,0.11694,1.00806,0.33167,0,0,1.04611,0.51389,0.20833,0,0,0.09333,1.28528,0.16083,0.0175,0.00306,0.79972,0.00278,0.00472,0.65306,0,0,0.08139,0.49528),
run = c(0,0.00111,0,0,0,0.00167,0.00194,0,0,0,0.00083,0.00083,0,0,0.00333,0.0025,0.00083,0,0,0.00139,0.00472,0,0,0,0.00194,0,0,0.08694,0,0,0,0.00111),
stairs = c(0.00917,0.00333,0,0,0,0.0575,0.01111,0,0,0.00389,0.03333,0.0075,0,0,0.03472,0.02472,0.00472,0.00194,0,0.00583,0.06722,0.0125,0,0,0.05806,0,0,0.01639,0,0,0.00417,0.03),
cycle = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.00778,0,0,0.01,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.00556,0),
WalkSlow = c(0.01222,0.02056,0.00389,0,0.03056,0.17417,0.03361,0,0,0.01889,0.35889,0.07778,0,0,0.07528,0.04222,0.03417,0,0,0.02444,0.13722,0.03361,0.00417,0,0.14,0,0.00056,0.08056,0,0,0.02278,0.08278),
WalkFast = c(0.10278,0.08639,0.02278,0,0.07417,0.66,0.32194,0,0,0.0975,0.64583,0.25139,0,0,0.97083,0.46861,0.17222,0,0,0.06861,1.14694,0.12667,0.01306,0.00278,0.65444,0.00194,0.0025,0.56944,0,0,0.0575,0.41))
```

I have tried some small codes, but, I have failed in almost all. The code below is what I could get, it's too big. I'm wondering if have any other way to do it smaller.

```
# LbNr = subjects' id
# Weekday = 1 Monday.... 7 Sunday
# Type = activities: A1. NonWorking, A2. Working, A4. SleepWeek, C0. Leisure, C4. SleepWeekend

# code
df %>% select(LbNr, Type, Weekday, Time, lie:IncTrunkWalk) %>% 
  group_by(LbNr, Type, Weekday) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), Time = sum(Time),lie   = sum(lie), sit = sum(sit), stand = sum(stand),
            move = sum(move),   walk = sum(walk), run = sum(run),   stairs = sum(stairs),
            cycle = sum(cycle), row = sum(row), WalkSlow = sum(WalkSlow),
            WalkFast = sum(WalkFast)) %>% 
  arrange(Weekday) %>% filter(Weekday %in% c('3':'7'))
```

So far I had another problem with this code. My problem is on Saturday "6", when I concatenate the time could be that Saturday receives activities that started on Friday (see the example below), sometimes will appear "A1. NonWorking" or "A4. SleepWeek", depends on the volunteer. I would like to sum this different activity on "C0. Leisure". If it was possible I would like to do it in one code.

```
#   LbNr      Type           Weekday   n   Time    lie    sit
#   <dbl>    <fct>             <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   
#8  22002 A2. Working            5     1   11.0   0.0103  6.77 
#9  22002 A4. SleepWeek          5     1   6.42   5.49    0.930  
#10 22002 A1. NonWorking         6     1   0.433  0.0169  0.302
#11 22002 C0. Leisure            6     1   15.7   0.245   9.78
#12 22002 C4. SleepWeekend       6     1   7.9    6.96    0.922
#13 22002 C0. Leisure            7     2   15.6   0.122   12.0



#I would like to get something like this.
#   LbNr      Type           Weekday   n   Time    lie    sit
#   <dbl>    <fct>             <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   
#8  22002 A2. Working            5     1   11.0   0.0103  6.77 
#9  22002 A4. SleepWeek          5     1   6.42   5.49    0.930  
#10 22002 C0. Leisure            6     1   16.133 0.2619  10.082
#11 22002 C4. SleepWeekend       6     1   7.9    6.96    0.922
#12 22002 C0. Leisure            7     2   15.6   0.122   12.0
```

For the first problem, I expect to get a small code. Moreover, if it was possible, I would expect to get a better code for the sum of different activities on Saturday.

Thanks in advance,
Luiz

Comment: In the first set of code, you are doing a range of column with `sum` that wouldn't work.  In the second, why is `sum` changed to `mean`

Comment: I need to `sum`, the second code I saw here, so I tried to see what I got. Moreover, I tried to change the `mean` for `sum`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: One potential isssue I see is the use of same variable in group_by and mutate_at `group_by(LbNr, Type, Weekday) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(LbNr:IncTrunkWalk),`. The `LbNr`

Comment: I can see it. I checked out without it and doesn't work as well. `df %>% group_by(LbNr, Type, Weekday) %>% summarise_at(vars(Time:IncTrunkWalk))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to try and answer your question without a better example (ie, you can `dput()` your data to give us a sample). But here is a solution to your last issue: "For the first problem, I expect to get a table with the sum of repeated rows for all columns. Moreover, if it was possible, I would expect to get a better code for the sum of different activities on Saturday."

```r
# create toy data of 3 different IDs, 3 different types, and repeated days
df <- data.frame(id=sample(c(1:3),100,T),
                 type=sample(letters[1:3],100,T),
                 day=sample(c(1:7),100,T),
                 matrix(runif(300),nrow=100),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

# gather data, summarize each activity column by ID, type and day
# and select Saturday==6
df %>% gather(k,v,-id,-type,-day) %>% 
  group_by(id,type,day,k) %>% 
  summarise(sum=sum(v)) %>% 
  filter(day==6) %>% 
  spread(k,sum)

# A tibble: 8 x 6
# Groups:   id, type, day [8]
     id type    day    X1    X2    X3
  <int> <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 a         6 1.85  3.26  2.09 
2     1 b         6 0.604 0.583 0.586
3     1 c         6 0.163 0.663 0.624
4     2 a         6 0.185 0.952 0.349
5     2 b         6 1.16  0.832 0.974
6     2 c         6 0.906 1.62  0.853
7     3 b         6 0.671 1.39  0.887
8     3 c         6 0.449 0.150 0.647
```

**UPDATE**
Here is an updated solution with the new data provided.

```r
df %>% group_by(LbNr,Type,Weekday) %>% summarise_all(.,sum)

# A tibble: 20 x 14
# Groups:   LbNr, Type [5]
    LbNr Type  Weekday   Time    lie     sit   stand    move    walk     run  stairs   cycle
   <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 22002 A1. ~       1  6.33  0.386  4.52e+0 0.726   0.499   0.189   0.00111 0.0075  0.00556
 2 22002 A1. ~       2  7.9   0.766  4.74e+0 1.28    0.611   0.489   0.00194 0.0111  0      
 3 22002 A1. ~       3  7.33  0.262  3.63e+0 2.04    0.941   0.449   0.00083 0.0114  0      
 4 22002 A1. ~       4 11.7   0.761  5.91e+0 2.54    1.19    1.25    0.00416 0.0394  0.00778
 5 22002 A1. ~       5  6.57  0.140  4.51e+0 1.12    0.51    0.254   0.00139 0.0183  0.01   
 6 22002 A1. ~       6  0.433 0.0169 3.02e-1 0.0589  0.0378  0.0175  0       0       0      
 7 22002 A2. ~       1  7.5   0.0792 5.90e+0 0.546   0.326   0.611   0.00111 0.0392  0      
 8 22002 A2. ~       2  9.83  0.0597 6.64e+0 1.64    0.595   0.842   0.00167 0.0575  0      
 9 22002 A2. ~       3  9.83  0.653  5.79e+0 1.82    0.525   1.01    0.00083 0.0333  0      
10 22002 A2. ~       4  5     0.383  2.80e+0 0.886   0.392   0.514   0.0025  0.0247  0      
11 22002 A2. ~       5 11.0   0.0103 6.77e+0 1.83    1.05    1.29    0.00472 0.0672  0      
12 22002 A4. ~       2  6.27  4.86   1.41e+0 0       0       0       0       0       0      
13 22002 A4. ~       3  6.83  5.69   1.15e+0 0       0       0       0       0       0      
14 22002 A4. ~       4  7.3   7.28   4.72e-3 0.00667 0.00667 0       0       0.00194 0      
15 22002 A4. ~       5  6.42  5.49   9.30e-1 0       0       0       0       0       0      
16 22002 C0. ~       6 15.7   0.245  9.78e+0 2.34    2.45    0.800   0.00194 0.0581  0      
17 22002 C0. ~       7 15.6   0.122  1.20e+1 1.80    0.940   0.656   0.0869  0.0164  0      
18 22002 C4. ~       1  6.33  5.75   5.84e-1 0       0       0       0       0       0      
19 22002 C4. ~       6  7.9   6.96   9.22e-1 0.00667 0.00806 0.00306 0       0       0      
20 22002 C4. ~       7  8.35  7.36   9.33e-1 0.0364  0.0208  0.00472 0       0       0      
# ... with 2 more variables: WalkSlow <dbl>, WalkFast <dbl>
```

I think this answers your first question about wanting a 'small code'. I don't understand your second question still about "I would expect to get a better code for the sum of different activities on Saturday." Does this mean that you want to sum across the different activities (lie, sit, etc.) for Saturday only? Or do you want to sum across different *types* (A2, C0, etc) of activities?

```r
df %>% group_by(LbNr,Type,Weekday) %>% summarise_all(.,sum) %>% 
  filter(Weekday==6)

# A tibble: 3 x 14
# Groups:   LbNr, Type [3]
   LbNr Type  Weekday   Time    lie   sit   stand    move    walk     run stairs cycle WalkSlow
  <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 22002 A1. ~       6  0.433 0.0169 0.302 0.0589  0.0378  0.0175  0       0          0  0.00417
2 22002 C0. ~       6 15.7   0.245  9.78  2.34    2.45    0.800   0.00194 0.0581     0  0.14   
3 22002 C4. ~       6  7.9   6.96   0.922 0.00667 0.00806 0.00306 0       0          0  0      
# ... with 1 more variable: WalkFast <dbl>

# summarise across different activities, for each column, on Saturday only
df %>% group_by(LbNr,Type,Weekday) %>% summarise_all(.,sum) %>% 
  filter(Weekday==6) %>% group_by(LbNr) %>% select(-Type,-Weekday) %>% 
  summarise_all(.,sum)

# A tibble: 1 x 12
   LbNr  Time   lie   sit stand  move  walk     run stairs cycle WalkSlow WalkFast
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 22002    24  7.22  11.0  2.41  2.49 0.820 0.00194 0.0581     0    0.144    0.670
```

Comment: Hi @kstew, I did what you have done, but I couldn't get it like in your example.
Related to first code, I wrote it again but I think it's not the smartest way to write. It's work!!! But the code is too big. Moreover, I need to implement this code with the one you did.
I edited the question with the data and the new code. I look forward to your reply, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Luiz, thanks for providing your data. But it doesn't work when I tried to read it as a dataframe, so I can't try your code with your data. Can you be more specific about what your expected output is? And can you show what you have tried with my code? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @kstew. Thanks for trying to help me and sorry for the long delay. I changed the data and I also changed my code to fit it, now I think you can reproduce my code. In addition, I gave another example of what I would expect as output. Thank's for your time

Comment: Hi Luiz, thanks again for providing the data. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @kstew. Thanks for helping me. Your first code was what I needed.

Comment: For the last code, maybe I wrote something wrong on the main text, I just realised. (**For Saturday**) I would like to sum "A1. NonWorking" with "C0. Leisure", another possibility that could happen is needing to sum "A4. SleepWeek" with "C4. SleepWeekend". Not everyone will have A1 or A4 on Saturday, it depends on whether the subject goes to bed early (before midnight resulting in A4 going on Saturday) or late (after midnight resulting in A1 going on Saturday). Moreover, I'm wondering if it's possible to do it along with the same code that you have done.

Comment: Hi Luiz, it sounds like you want to sum across two different Types in your data? If so, instead of grouping by Type, you can filter the Types that you want, then summarise all of the columns like before: `df %>% filter(grepl('A1|C0',Type)) %>% select(-Type) %>% 
  group_by(LbNr,Weekday) %>% summarise_all(.,sum)`. This will return one row per weekday summing all instances of A1 and C0 together.

Comment: Hi Kstew. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Hi @kstew, I'm wondering if you could help me. I have this code df %>% group_by(LbNr,Type,Weekday) %>% summarise_all(.,sum) %>% filter(Weekday %in% c('3':'7'), Weekday | Type %in% c('A2.Working'), Time >= 6) %>% select(-Weekday) %>% group_by(LbNr, Type) %>% summarise_all(., mean, na.rm = TRUE) to sum the working days with more than 6 hours, but I couldn't delete the whole day under 6. Because of this, when I run the code the workday has more than 24 hours.