# How to summarise a dataframe retaining all the columns

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, aggregate, data-wrangling

Consider the following dataframe:

```
dummy_df <- tibble(
  A=c("ABC", "ABC", "BCD", "CDF", "CDF", "CDF"),
  B=c(0.25, 0.25, 1.23, 0.58, 0.58, 0.58),
  C=c("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "amet", "something", "else"),
  D=c("up", "up", "down", "down", "down", "down"),
  E=c(132, 132, 243, 512, 512, 512),
  F=c("m1", "m1", "m5", "m3", "m3", "m3"),
  G=c("val", "val", "mur", "mad", "mad", "mad"),
  H=c("grx", "grx", "bcn", "sal", "sal", "sal"),
  I=c(1.68, 1.68, 2.31, 3.12, 3.12, 3.12),
  J=c("p", "p", "f", "p", "p", "p"),
  K=c(100, 100, 200, 143, 143, 143)
)

# A tibble: 6 × 11
  A         B C         D         E F     G     H         I J         K
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>     <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1 ABC    0.25 lorem     up      132 m1    val   grx    1.68 p       100
2 ABC    0.25 ipsum     up      132 m1    val   grx    1.68 p       100
3 BCD    1.23 dolor     down    243 m5    mur   bcn    2.31 f       200
4 CDF    0.58 amet      down    512 m3    mad   sal    3.12 p       143
5 CDF    0.58 something down    512 m3    mad   sal    3.12 p       143
6 CDF    0.58 else      down    512 m3    mad   sal    3.12 p       143
```

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w), I have managed to collapse column C so that its value is concatenated into a string for every unique row value of column A.

```
dummy_df %>% group_by(A) %>% summarise(hits = toString(C), nhits=n())

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  A     hits                  nhits
  <chr> <chr>                 <int>
1 ABC   lorem, ipsum              2
2 BCD   dolor                     1
3 CDF   amet, something, else     3
```

However, I'm loosing every other column information, which are essential to me. How can I retain information about **all the columns** while collapsing column C? Ideally it should be done without having to hard-code the columns names, since the number of columns can vary depending on the dataset.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57243521/how-to-summarise-all-columns-using-group-by-and-summarise), but the example shown doesn't create new variables so I haven't been able to make it work.

This is what I'm looking for:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 12
  A     hits                  nhits     B D         E F     G     H         I J         K
  <chr> <chr>                 <int> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1 ABC   lorem, ipsum              2  0.25 up      132 m1    val   grx    1.68 p       100
2 BCD   dolor                     1  1.23 down    243 m5    mur   bcn    2.31 f       200
3 CDF   amet, something, else     3  0.58 down    512 m3    mad   sal    3.12 p       143
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we assume that all fields other than `C` will contain repeating values for each `A`-group, then we can do this:

```r
dummy_df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarize(
    nhits = n(),
    across(where(is.character), ~ toString(unique(.))),
    across(where(~ !is.character(.)), ~ unique(.))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 × 12
#   A     nhits C                     D     F     G     H     J         B     E     I     K
#   <chr> <int> <chr>                 <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 ABC       2 lorem, ipsum          up    m1    val   grx   p      0.25   132  1.68   100
# 2 BCD       1 dolor                 down  m5    mur   bcn   f      1.23   243  2.31   200
# 3 CDF       3 amet, something, else down  m3    mad   sal   p      0.58   512  3.12   143
```

In this case, since all other variables are repeating, everything stays as-is. If, however, we have variability, then I've set up a catch, where strings are combined (with `toString`) and differing numbers cause repeat rows.

```r
dummy_df$H[1] <- "GRX"
dummy_df$K[1] <- 99
 %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarize(
    nhits = n(),
    across(where(is.character), ~ toString(unique(.))),
    across(where(~ !is.character(.)), ~ unique(.))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 4 × 12
  A     nhits C                     D     F     G     H        J         B     E     I     K
  <chr> <int> <chr>                 <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 ABC       2 lorem, ipsum          up    m1    val   GRX, grx p      0.25   132  1.68    99
2 ABC       2 lorem, ipsum          up    m1    val   GRX, grx p      0.25   132  1.68   100
3 BCD       1 dolor                 down  m5    mur   bcn      f      1.23   243  2.31   200
4 CDF       3 amet, something, else down  m3    mad   sal      p      0.58   512  3.12   143
```

The `across` function iterates over multiple columns. The `where` function allows us to subset columns by something about their values, where for `character` columns we will apply `toString`, and for others we'll go with `unique`. This means that string columns should never add rows, but non-strings may.

An alternative for the number-like columns would be to use `first(.)` instead of `unique(.)`, which will silently discard all but the first value in each column by group. Using the same modified data, we would see this, where the key difference is that `K` has discarded the `100` values since the first value is `99`.

```r
dummy_df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarize(
    nhits = n(), 
    across(where(is.character), ~ toString(unique(.))),
    across(where(~ !is.character(.)), ~ first(.))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 × 12
#   A     nhits C                     D     F     G     H        J         B     E     I     K
#   <chr> <int> <chr>                 <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 ABC       2 lorem, ipsum          up    m1    val   GRX, grx p      0.25   132  1.68    99
# 2 BCD       1 dolor                 down  m5    mur   bcn      f      1.23   243  2.31   200
# 3 CDF       3 amet, something, else down  m3    mad   sal      p      0.58   512  3.12   143
```

You can choose to use `first` with string columns as well, if you choose, which could simplify the logic to a single `across`:

```r
dummy_df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarize(
    nhits = n(),
    across(everything(), ~ first(.))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 × 12
#   A     nhits     B C     D         E F     G     H         I J         K
#   <chr> <int> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 ABC       2  0.25 lorem up      132 m1    val   GRX    1.68 p        99
# 2 BCD       1  1.23 dolor down    243 m5    mur   bcn    2.31 f       200
# 3 CDF       3  0.58 amet  down    512 m3    mad   sal    3.12 p       143
```

Note that we've lost `H`'s `"grx"` (since `"GRX"` was first) as well as `K`'s value of `100`.

The `data.table` variant of this last code-block can be simply:

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dummy_df)[, c(.(nhits = .N), lapply(.SD, first)), by = A]
```

and a base R rendition? Perhaps not as "pretty" :-)

```r
Reduce(
  function(a, b) merge(a, b, by = "A", all = TRUE), 
  list(
    setNames(aggregate(C ~ A, dummy_df, FUN = length), c("A", "nhits")), 
    aggregate(C ~ A, dummy_df, FUN = toString),
    aggregate(. ~ A, subset(dummy_df, select = -C), FUN = function(z) z[1])
  )
)
#     A nhits                     C    B    D   E  F   G   H    I J   K
# 1 ABC     2          lorem, ipsum 0.25   up 132 m1 val GRX 1.68 p  99
# 2 BCD     1                 dolor 1.23 down 243 m5 mur bcn 2.31 f 200
# 3 CDF     3 amet, something, else 0.58 down 512 m3 mad sal 3.12 p 143
```

Comment: The question has been updated with a better reprex, I didn't make myself clear, sorry for that.

Answer (score 4):

We could do it this way:

```
library(dplyr) #>= 1.1.0
dummy_df %>%
  summarise(hits = toString(C), nhits = n(), B = unique(B), .by = A)
```

**OR**

```
library(dplyr)

dummy_df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise(hits = toString(C), nhits = n(), B = unique(B))
```

```
 A     hits                  nhits     B
  <chr> <chr>                 <int> <dbl>
1 ABC   lorem, ipsum              2  0.25
2 BCD   dolor                     1  1.23
3 CDF   amet, something, else     3  0.58
>
```

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned it but maybe I wasn't clear. I need to retain every column in the original df, not only B. Is it still possible to accomplish this with this approach? (without having to write down manually 20 columns, of course :D)

Comment: @jpm92 Just `group_by(A, B)` if B is always the same

Comment: I am sorry but my output is exact the same as your desired output?

Comment: I know it is, but as I mentioned, I have 20 more columns apart from B that I need to retain that I didn't include in the reprex to simplify it, how could I retain all of them without having to manually specify them in the code?

Comment: Could you add an extended example?

Comment: Question has been updated. I have managed to accomplish what I was looking for with reframe() and across() but it's still not the best approach I think. Let me know if you can improve it and thanks a lot, really :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dummy_df)[, .(B = first(B), hits = toString(C), nhits = .N), by = A]
```